# Как решить проблему не целых чисел?

Tags: python, математика

Суть задачи в том, чтобы узнать можно ли из числа, которое дано на вход получить пару чисел: целое число возведенное в целочисленную степень. Например если дано число 81, то пара будет [9, 2], т.к. 9 в квадрате = 81. Также необходимо эту пару вывести, если пар > 1, то допускается вывести только одну из них, а если пар нет, то вернуть None. Я написал следующий код:

```
from math import log


def degree(val):
    for x in range(2, 1000000):
        lg = log(val, x)
        if int(lg) == lg and lg >= 2:
            return [x, int(log(val, x))]

    return None


print(degree(59049))
```

Проблема заключается в том, что в некоторых случаях я получаю вместо целого числа подобное: 3.0000000000000004, 4.999999999999999 и тд.

Округлять эти числа скорее всего не самое верное решение, так как алгоритм вычисления завязан на сравнении округленного и не округленного числа. Заранее спасибо за какую либо помощь.

PS: проблемы начинаются с числа 125, т.е. (5 в 3 степени)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Работать с целыми числами. И незачем перерывать все числа до миллионов — проще всего работать с показателями степени, их меньше. Вот мой вариант:

```
from math import log

def Degree(n):
    for b in range(2, int(log(n)/log(2))+1):
        a = int(n**(1/b)+0.5)
        if a**b == n:
            return [a, b]

    return None
```

Answer (score 3):

Так вы работайте в целых числах - проверяйте делимость исходного `val` на числа в диапазоне до `sqrt(val)`

Если `val` целочисленно делится на `n`, и только на `n` (в процессе деления в конце концов получили 1), то  вы нашли то, что нужно.

```
def degree(val):
    n = 2
    while n * n <= val:
        t = val
        p = 0
        while t % n == 0:
            t //= n
            p += 1
        if t == 1:
            return n, p
        n += 1
    return None
```

Answer (score 2):

Другие ответы про работу с целыми числами более правильные по сути, но я хочу вам показать, что и оставаясь в пространстве чисел с плавающей точкой в питоне тоже можно получать точные/правильные результаты. `Python`, как и многие другие языки, поддерживает **точный формат чисел с плавающей запятой** `decimal`. И я тут использую формулу для вычисления логарифма с любым основанием через натуральный логарифм: `log(a, b) = log(a)/log(b)`, потому что в модуле `decimal` есть только натуральный логарифм и логарифм с основанием 10. И ещё я вывожу все ответы, а не только первый:

```
from decimal import Decimal

def degree(val):
    log_val = Decimal(val).ln();
    for x in range(2, int(val ** 0.5) + 1):
        lg = log_val / Decimal(x).ln() 
        if int(lg) == lg and lg >= 2:
            yield [x, int(lg)]
    return None

print(list(degree(59049)))
```

Вывод:

```
[[3, 10], [9, 5], [243, 2]]
```

Comment: `Decimal` - формат с настраиваемой точностью, но он не абсолютно точный. Проблемы начнутся уже на `degree(8)`. Чтобы улучшить результат, можно в проверке использовать `x ** round(lg) == val`. И в выводе `int` на `round`, соответственно. Это и с `float` поможет, хоть и в меньшей степени.

Comment: Спасибо за доп информацию, полезно

Comment: @extrn Ну тогда лучше всё-таки в целых числах всё считать. Но про `decimal` иметь представление полезно )

Answer (score 1):

Связка `lg = log(val, x)`, `int(lg) == lg` будет работать только если логарифм считается точно (в тех случаях когда он может быть посчитан точно). Это, к сожалению, не так. Точность логарифма не гарантирована.

Мы можем можем использовать логарифм чтобы получить приближенное значение, но проверять его надо с помощью точной арифметики. Например: `lg = round(log(val, x))`, `x ** lg == val`. В первой части приведение к целому заменено на округление (чтобы небольшую неточность не превращать в катастрофу, как это делает `int`). Проверка заменена на точную, которая вычисляется в целых числах.

Может ли новый код ошибаться? Хотя гарантий достаточной точности вычисления логарифма у нас по-прежнему нет, можно убедится что логарифм считается достаточно точно чтобы погрешность результата никогда не превышала `0.5`.

Вторая ошибка - верхняя граница `x`. Для `val = 1000002000001` (`= 1000001^2`) программа ничего не вернёт. Границу надо увеличить до `sqrt(val)`:

Вот это будет работать...

```
from math import log, isqrt


def degree(val):
    for x in range(2, isqrt(val) + 1):
        lg = round(log(val, x))
        if x ** lg == val and lg >= 2:
            return [x, lg]

    return None


print(degree(int(input())))
```

... но медленно. Сложность алгоритма примерно `sqrt(val)` - столько различных значений `x` мы пробуем если `val` не степень какого-нибудь числа.

Можно сделать лучше. Будем перебирать заначения `lg` от двух до чего-то там и вычислять по ним подходящий `x`. Затем снова точная проверка в целых числах:

```
def degree(val):
    lg = 2
    while True:
        x = round(val ** (1 / lg))
        if x == 1:
            break
        if x ** lg == val:
            return [x, lg]
        lg += 1

    return None


print(degree(int(input())))
```

Выражение `val ** (1 / lg)` вычисляет корень степени `lg` из `val`. Примерно, конечно, но, кажется, работает. Без строгих гарантий.

Скорость стала значительно лучше. Количество итераций цикла не больше `log(val, 1.5)`. Другими словами время работы пропорционально (примерно) длине вводимого числа. Отличный результат.

Вернёмся к "не строгим гарантиям" и сломаем нашу новую быструю программу. Вещественный тип в Питоне точно хранит не более 16 десятичных знаков. Подадим на вход число `(10^16 + 1)^2` (`= 100000000000000020000000000000001`) и она ничего не найдет, так как не может извлечь корень квадратный достаточно точно.

Шутки в сторону - простые приближенные методы или работают медленно или быстро начинают врать. К счастью, извлечь корень из целого числа можно двоичным поиском точно. Новая программа будет медленее двух кандидатов на небольших числах, но её рабочий диапазон ограничен только памятью вашего компьютера и вашим свободным временем. И что значит "медленнее"? Новая программа обрабатывает числа из десятков тысяч цифр за доли секунды, не так уж и медленно:

```
def bsearch(pred, low, high):
    assert not pred(low) and pred(high)
    while low < high - 1:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        assert low < mid < high
        if pred(mid):
            high = mid
        else:
            low = mid
        assert not pred(low) and pred(high)
    assert low + 1 == high

    return low


def iroot(n, e):

    def pred(b):
        return n < b ** e

    high = 1
    while not pred(high):
        high *= 2
    
    return bsearch(pred, 0, high)


def any_iroot(n):
    e = 2
    while True:
        r = iroot(n, e)
        if r ** e == n:
            return r, e
        if r == 1:
            return None
        e += 1


print(any_iroot(int(input())))
```

> ```
> $ time echo 100000000000000020000000000000001 | python any_iroot_int.py
> (10000000000000001, 2)
>
> real  0m0.033s
> user  0m0.024s
> sys   0m0.004s
> ```